# I need to replace the sprite at runtime Unity 2d

Tags: unity, c#

I need a help, I have some code in Unity that should replace the player's sprite at runtime. But this code does not make it correctly, it does't make the change. Could you help me? Thanks

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerBehavior : MonoBehaviour {

  public enum Skins 
  {
    normal,
    verde
  }

  private Skins skinAtual; 

  private Rigidbody2D player;
  public float height;
  private Transform posicao;
  public float jumpForce = 10f;
  private AudioSource audio;
  public DeathMenu deathMenu;
  private float initialX;
  public float goBackSpeed = 10f;
  Object[] BGMusics;
  //private SpriteRenderer sprite;

  public SpriteRenderer[] sprites;

  public Sprite skinVerde, skinNormal; 


  void Start () {

    //skinAtual = Skins.normal;
    skinAtual = Skins.verde;
    //sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
    player = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    BGMusics = Resources.LoadAll ("Music/BG");
    initialX = transform.position.x;


    //skinVerde = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Sprites/BOYrECORTADOvERDE");
    skinVerde = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Sprites/PersonagemFatiado_verde");
    skinNormal = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Sprites/PersonagemFatiado");

  }

  private void UpdateSkin(Sprite novaSprite)
  {
    foreach (var item in sprites) {
      item.sprite = novaSprite;
    }
  }


  void Update () 
  {

    switch (skinAtual) {

    case Skins.normal:
      UpdateSkin (skinNormal);
      break; 
    case Skins.verde:
      UpdateSkin (skinVerde);
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape))
      Pause.INSTANCE.Pausing ();

    if (Pause.isPaused)
      return;       

    if (Application.isEditor)
      inputComputer ();
    else if(Application.isMobilePlatform)
      inputMobile ();

    FixePosition ();
  }

  void FixePosition()
  {
    if (transform.position.x <= initialX) return;

    var newPX = Mathf.Lerp (transform.position.x, initialX, Time.deltaTime * goBackSpeed);
    transform.position = new Vector3 (newPX, transform.position.y); 

  } 

  private void inputMobile(){
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
      playerJump ();
  }

  private void inputComputer(){

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
      playerJump ();
  }

  private void playerJump(){
    if (player.transform.position.y <= -8.93000f ) 
    {
      player.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, height * jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
      MusicManager.INSTANCE.JumpSound ();
    }
  }

  void PlayRandom(){
    int i = Random.Range(0, BGMusics.Length); // index sortido
    AudioClip m = (AudioClip) BGMusics[i]; // uma referencia ao audioclip sortido
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(m); // tocamos esse audioclip
  }

  void Reset(){
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().playOnAwake = false; // aqui tira o play on awake do audio source
  }


  // CONFIGURANDO OS TRIGGERS E SUAS ACOES
  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
  {
    if(col.gameObject.CompareTag("Heart"))
    {
      Score.INSTANCE.AddPoints ();
      col.gameObject.SetActive (false);
      Handheld.Vibrate ();
      //TOCAR
      PlayRandom ();

    } 
    else 
    {
      if (col.gameObject.tag == "Doctor") 
      {
        MusicManager.INSTANCE.DeathSong ();
        player.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        Handheld.Vibrate ();
        ToggleEndMenu();
      }
    }

  }

  void ToggleEndMenu()
  {
    deathMenu.ToggleEndMenu (Score.INSTANCE.GetScore ()); //Send to DeathMenu the Score value
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code for UpdateSkin iterates through sprites[] - Have you set the SpriteRenderers in the Editor? (it's `public SpriteRenderer[] sprites;`)

Comment: "it does not make it correctly" does not describe the problem. What is the exact intent of your code, and what does it do instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void UpdateSkin(Sprite novaSprite){
foreach (var item in sprites)
    item.sprite = novaSprite;
}
```

The above function uses a for-each loop to assign specific sprites to the `sprites[]` which you defined at the top of type `spriteRenderer`

**Here's what you can do:**

1. Make sure you have assigned SpriteRenderer references properly in the inspector tab.
2. Make sure that

   `skinVerde = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Sprites/PersonagemFatiado_verde");`

   `skinNormal = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Sprites/PersonagemFatiado");`

are actually getting the references for the sprites instead of null. Try assigning those sprites in inspector tab instead of loading like that and see if it works.

**Tip:**
Try using print statements to make sure that functions are executing and look out for errors in the editor when pressing the play button, they are a life-saver.

Answer (score 0):

your object should have a `spriteRenderer` Component attached to it in the inspector. just update it using code below:

```
public Sprite mySprite;

this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = mySprite;
```

my sprite is public so you can see it in inspector. just use second in every event you want to change the sprite of you object